# What could cause two hosts on the same network not to be able to ping each other?

Tags: networking, ping

I connected my laptop to my modem through WLAN and connected my PC to the modem by LAN.

The IP address of my laptop is `192.168.1.3`.
The IP address of my PC is `192.168.1.4`.

I am able to ping my default gateway from both the hosts. The default gateway is my modem and the IP is `192.168.1.1`.

But the ping from my laptop to PC and vice versa fails. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ping may be failing due to a firewall on your PC. Windows Firewall in its default setting does not respond to ICMP requests. Turn firewall OFF temporarily and try again.